# Securely encrypt appsettings connection string using IDataProtectionProvider in dot net core3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, encryption, appsettings

I have successfully used **IDataProtectionProvider** to encrypt/decrypt in different controllers and no issues with it.
However i also want to use the same for securely encrypting/decrypting  the connection string stored in appsettings.json. Since the GetConnectionString() is called in the same startup.cs where the AddDataProtection servive itself is registered, i really couldn't figure out how to do it. Any help appreciated. Thanks.
Here is my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            Action<GlobalData> gData = (g =>...);
            services.Configure(gData);
            services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<GlobalData>>().Value);

            services.AddDataProtection();            

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<ImgContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ImgContext")));

            services.AddTransient<EmailHelper>();

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>...).AddDefaultTokenProviders()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ImgContext>();

            services.AddMvc(options =>...);

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>...);
            services.AddSingleton<DataProtectionPurposeStrings>();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we could build an intermediate service provider and resolve the registered service in the ConfigureServices method.

For exmaple:

I guess you use `DataProtectionPurposeStrings` to protect or unprotect  the conntionstring.

You could firstly get the encrypted connection string by using `Configuration.GetConnectionString("ImgContext")` and then use DataProtectionPurposeStrings class to decrypt it.

Like below:

Notice: Since I don't know how you decrypt and encrypt using DataProtection, you should modify the codes by yourself.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDataProtection();
        Action<GlobalData> gData = (g => ...);
        services.AddSingleton<DataProtectionPurposeStrings>();

        //Build an intermediate service provider
        var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        //Resolve the services from the service provider
        var datapro = sp.GetService<DataProtectionPurposeStrings>();
        IDataProtector protector = datapro.CreateProtector("ConStrXyz");


        services.Configure(gData);
        services.AddSingleton(resolver => resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<GlobalData>>().Value);



        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        //use datapro class to decrypt the connection string
        services.AddDbContext<ImgContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(protector.Unprotect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ImgContext"))));

        services.AddTransient<EmailHelper>();

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => ...).AddDefaultTokenProviders()
          .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ImgContext>();

        services.AddMvc(options => ...);

        services.AddAuthorization(options => ...);

    }
```

Comment: Quick and Fantastic one. Marked as Answer though a small Edit was required to qualify as the Working-One. Made the edit myself hoping you don't mind. Thanks once again!

Comment: However the creation of an extra service provider (sp) leaves a Warning that it results in the creation of additional copy of Singleton services. Ignore or not ??